# How do I schedule a job to be run at a specific date in Hangfire

Tags: c#, batch-processing, cronexpression, hangfire

Hangfire.io supports making a CRON-like scheduling of recurring jobs. But how do I specify, that a specific job should be run once, at a specific date/time, e.g. that a job should be run June 4th 2016, at 16:22 - and only at that specific point in time?

A similar way to ask the same question could be: how large a subset of the CRON expression described [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression), is supported by Hangfire? (The described CRON expression supports a "Year"-field which could be used).

Also, do you think Hangfire is the best choice to schedule one-off batch jobs in the first place, provided that I use Hangfire for job processing?

Comment: I know that is a old question. But since cron expressions doesn't handle years just (minute, hour, day, month, day of week) the following cron expression: `22 16 4 6 *` means:  “At 16:22 on day-of-month 4 in June.” - Please see the following site: https://crontab.guru/#22_16_4_6_*

Answer (score 3):

You can use BackgroundJob.Schedule(Expression> methodCall, DateTimeOffsetdt) method.

```
BackgroundJob.Schedule(methodCall, enqueueAt);
```

Answer (score 1):

In one of my application we schedule a job for only once run in a particular date time. Look into below code

```
  public string Schedule(Expression<Action> methodToCall, DateTimeOffset enqueueAt)
    {
        return BackgroundJob.Schedule(methodToCall, enqueueAt);
    }
```

Where enqueueAt is the date time when you want to run the job.

Answer (score 0):

Cron expression with Year is not supported by Hangfire.

To run a job at specific point in time, use following `schedule` method overload from `BackgroundJob` class.

```
public static string Schedule([InstantHandle] Expression<Action> methodCall, DateTimeOffset enqueueAt);

BackgroundJob.Schedule(() => Console.Write("test"), new DateTime(2016, 6, 4, 16, 22, 0));
```

Comment: When you try to specify year part in cron expression by calling `RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate("test", () => Console.Write("test"),"44 16 2 FEB * 2016");` It throws this exception  `{"'44 16 2 FEB * 2016' is not a valid crontab expression. It must contain at least 5 components of a schedule (in the sequence of minutes, hours, days, months, days of week)."}`

Comment: Thats not a valid CRON format that Hangfire supports.  Refer to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression