# Does Hangfire support one time (Non-recurring) cron jobs?

Tags: c#, .net-core, hangfire

I need to set up an non-recurring Hangfire cron job that will run on a specific date and time for one time, I will have a pre-determined job id that would manage the job (hence preferring a cron operation - potentially changing the job schedule)

Comment: Does scheduling a job not work? `BackgroundJob.Schedule(methodCall..)°

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I schedule a job to be run at a specific date in Hangfire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35698361/how-do-i-schedule-a-job-to-be-run-at-a-specific-date-in-hangfire)

Comment: Scheduling a job works, but in Hangfire either you can run a cron job (recurring) or a instant job that will be scheduled immediately, I was looking for a non-recurring cron job which they don't support as of December 2020 (I have my answer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer: Scheduling a job works, but in Hangfire either you can run a cron job (recurring) or a instant job that will be scheduled immediately for execution, I was looking for a non-recurring cron job which they don't support as of December 2020 (I have my answer).

Comment: Please use a tick below the answer to mark it as answered.

Comment: @Pri You DID see that this is a self answer ... on a 2y old question?

Comment: @PatrickArtner I missed that it is two years old. Thanks for bringing it into my attention. Would be better to mark it as ticked anyway because I saw 'SOLVED' in the title earlier.