# How to schedule a Hangfire background job on a specific time AND in a specific queue?

Tags: c#, hangfire

I use [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/) for scheduling jobs. In my setup I have defined two distinct queues. One is used to process recurrent jobs and jobs with a 'low' priority. The other queue is used for jobs that have a 'high' priority which are created ad hoc resulting from user input. Non recurrent jobs are scheduled like this to ensure they end up in the correct queue:

```
var client = new BackgroundJobClient();
var state = new EnqueuedState(queueName);
client.Create(methodCall, state);
```

All works fine, but now I have a new requirement where I need to delay execution for 'high priority' jobs under certain conditions.

I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35698361/how-do-i-schedule-a-job-to-be-run-at-a-specific-date-in-hangfire) question here on Stack Overflow which mentions the BackgroundJobClient.Schedule operation accepts an enqueueAt parameter:

```
var client = new BackgroundJobClient();
client.Schedule(methodCall, enqueueAt);
```

Unfortunately this Schedule operation does not provide me with an option to define the queue. Jobs scheduled using this approach end up in the 'default' queue of Hangfire. Any idea how I can implement the job scheduling delay together with having the ability to determine the queue at runtime?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an argument that defines the queue name for `methodCall`. Based on [discussion here](https://discuss.hangfire.io/t/one-queue-for-the-whole-farm-and-one-queue-by-server/490/4), you can selectively run the method on queue of your choice. `UseQueueFromParameter` should solve the issue you are facing

Comment: This is an interesting approach. I will accept this as answer, although I am not 100% sure I will implement it this way. I am thinking about an approach where I introduce a new component that is responsible for detecting if a delay is required and if so, it will reschedule itself at the end of the delay period. The next execution will then be at a time the delay period is ended, and then the component will schedule the original request in the expected queue.